# invariant spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n $ which is invertible.
There is also an invariant subspace $W$ that implies $\dim W = k $

I need to prove that there is an invariant subspace that its dimension is $n-k$

Any suggestions? I think that I need to find basis that $T$ is represented by blocks diagonal matrix but I do not know how to do it. thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 1):

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ in Jordan canonical form.  Then you get invariant subspaces of any dimension $k$ from $1$ to $n$ by requiring the last $n-k$ entries  to be $0$.

Unfortunately you're working in ${\mathbb R}^n$ instead of ${\mathbb C}^n$, so things are more complicated.  But you might be able to work with the real Jordan Form (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_canonical_form#Real_matrices)

Comment: I don't understand how you create the n-k invariant space

Comment: If $A$ is upper triangular, $\{x: x_{k+1} = \ldots = x_n = 0\}$ is invariant.

Answer (score -1):

Let $(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k)$ be a basis of $W$.  And let $v_{1}\not\in W$.  We can create an invariant subspace with basis $v_1,T(v_1),T^2(v_1),\ldots,T^{r_1}(v_1)$ for some $r$.  In such a manor we can create a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of the form $(w_1,\ldots,w_k,v_1,\ldots,T^{r_1}(v_1),\ldots,v_m,\ldots,T^{r_m}(v_m))$  Then span$(v_1,\ldots,T^{r_1}(v_1),\ldots,v_m,\ldots,T^{r_m}(v_m))$ is an invariant subspace with dimension $n-k$

Below is a hint that I gave earlier that doesn't lead anywhere.

Then$(T(u_1),T(u_2),\ldots,T(u_k))$ is basis of $W$ (because $T$ is invertable and $W$ is invarant) and can be extended to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, say $(T(u_1),T(u_2),\ldots,T(u_k),v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{n-k})$.  Then what can we say about span$(T^{-1}(v_1),T^{-1}(v_2),\ldots,T^{-1}(v_{n-k}))$?

Comment: it is T-invariant? can you explain?

Comment: I'll be back on in ~ 20 mins to give more details.

Comment: It is not invariant.

Comment: I agree that we cannot just claim that span$(T^{-1}(v_{1}),\ldots,T^{-1}(v_{n-k}))$ is invariant.  Perhaps a better way to approach it would be to go the other direction.  Take $v\not\in W$ and consider the sequence $(v,T(v),T^2(v),\ldots)$ Let $n$ be the smallest integer for which $T^n(v)$ is a linear combination of $v,T(v),\ldots,T^{n-1}(v)$  Then we have that $v,T(v),\ldots, T^{n-1}(v)$ are linearly independent and $V=$span$(v,T(v),\ldots, T^{n-1}(v))$ is invariant under $T$.  Note that $T^n(v)\not\in W$ because $W$ is invariant under both $T$ and $T^{-1}$

Comment: but we need an invariant space that its dimension is n-k

Comment: I should not have used $n$ above for the smallest integer for which $T^{n}(v)$ is a linear combination of ...   Anyway, We can keep creating these invariant subspaces until we have formed a complete basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.  What do we know about the sum of invariant subspaces?

Comment: ok but how do you know that you stop at n-k-1?

Comment: You are correct, and so then we pick a new vector that is linearly independent and start over.  The process must eventually terminate because we are working with a finite dimensional space.

Comment: it is direct sum and it is invariant also. thanks you are amazing!