# complementary T invariant subspace existance

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

$T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is invertible and there exists an invariant subspace W s.t $dimW=k$. Prove that has an invariant subspace with dimension $n-k$.

**Thoughts**
It seems intuitivley that it's true, but I don't think of a way to start proving this...
Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598502/invariant-spaces

Comment: I guess the $(n-k)$-dimensional subspace is not complementary to $W$, otherwise the statement is false (just take the matrix $\left(\matrix{1&1\\0&1}\right)$)